# Casting int to string in Linq where clause

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a 'where' clause in a linq query where I have to cast an int to a string, I have tried reading similar encounters in SO but I still have difficulties applying the solutions in my method. This is the line that will throw  the 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' error, any help is appreciated:

**|| (p.ProductID != null && p.ProductID.ToString().Contains(s)) :**

```
  public void search(string s)
    {
        CommerceEntities db = new CommerceEntities();

            var products = from p in db.Products

                           where (p.ModelName != null && p.ModelName.Contains(s))
                           || (p.ProductID != null && p.ProductID.ToString().Contains(s))
                           || (p.ModelNumber != null && p.ModelNumber.Contains(s))
                           || (p.Description != null && p.Description.Contains(s))

                           select new
                           {
                               // Display the items 
                               ProductID = p.ProductID,
                               ProductImage = p.ProductImage,
                               UnitCost = p.UnitCost
                           };

            ListView_Products.DataSourceID = null;
            ListView_Products.DataSource = products;

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`

Comment: Just a question, you are trying to cast an int to a string, and then see if the casted string contains a string? this would work only if S was an int as well right?, so why not pass an int instead of a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In EF, There is no overload for int so you need to cast to a double or a decimal. You have to use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx)

Like this:

```
        p.ProductID != null &&  SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.ProductID).Contains(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing the exception because at the end of the first line you closed out the where method. You are missing a ( that groups those lines together.

```
where ((p.ModelName != null && p.ModelName.Contains(s)) ||
       (p.ProductID != null && p.ProductID.ToString().Contains(s)) || 
       (p.ModelNumber != null && p.ModelNumber.Contains(s)) ||
       (p.Description != null && p.Description.Contains(s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linq to Entities you cannot use C# methods inside the query expression.
It will work if it is Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an integer variable Convert your string s in it than use
     p.ProductID == (intval))

Means Your code would be like this

```
public void search(string s)
{
    CommerceEntities db = new CommerceEntities();
     int val = Convert.ToInt32(s);
    IQueryable<Product> product = db.Products ;
        var products = from p in db.Products

                       where (p.ModelName != null && p.ModelName.Contains(s))
                       || (p.ProductID != null && p.ProductID == val)
                       || (p.ModelNumber != null && p.ModelNumber.Contains(s))
                       || (p.Description != null && p.Description.Contains(s))

                       select new
                       {
                           // Display the items 
                           ProductID = p.ProductID,
                           ProductImage = p.ProductImage,
                           UnitCost = p.UnitCost
                       };

        ListView_Products.DataSourceID = null;
        ListView_Products.DataSource = products;

}
```

Comment: This I believe will not be ideal because the user would have to key in the exact ProductID characters to return any search results because of "=="

Comment: Then you have to remove  ToString() from Product ID checking because it is not supported in Linq .

Answer (score 0):

A descent workaround which still evaluates the query in the DB is the following:

```
Convert.ToString(p.ProductID).Contains(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the .ToString() method in Entity Framework Linq queries.