# Converting an int to string for a searchbar function C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have written an application in ASP.NET MVC and have implemented a search bar. This search bar is enabled for multiple fields. The problem I am having is enabling the search for an ID field of type int. It seems like I need to only have string values in my search field. Is there a way to convert the ID field to string type so I can also be able to search for that?

Here is the code i'm using. It works for first name and last name, but not when I have the ID part enabled.

Any help is appreciated!

```
 public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.LastSortParm = sortOrder == "LastName" ? "LastDesc" : "LastName";

        ViewBag.FirstSortParm = sortOrder == "FirstName" ? "FirstDesc" : "FirstName";

        ViewBag.IDSortParm = sortOrder == "ID" ? "RVHDesc" : "ID";

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) //creates the code for the search bar
        {
            doctors = doctors.Where(d => d.Last_Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) //insert to upper or lower so that case is ignored
                                   || d.First_Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
             || d.RVH_ID_.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  If `d.RVH_ID_` is an integer, then you will need to call `ToString()` before the `ToUpper()` or you will get an error about no such method exists for integer.

Comment: Also, you have an extra `;` in your `.Where()` before the last line.

Comment: It says "int does not contain a definition for ToUpper". So I should write something like     d.RVH_ID_.ToString(Contains(searchString.ToUpper())))); ?

Comment: Why are we calling `ToUpper` on a string containing an integer? Is lowercase `1` different from uppercase `1`? Am I getting that out of touch?

Comment: @wgraham should I just cut out the     ToUpper parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `d.RVH_ID_` field is an `int` then you will need to call `ToString()` on it before your `ToUpper()` call.  Try this:

```
doctors = doctors.Where(d => d.Last_Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
         || d.First_Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
         || d.RVH_ID_.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
```

As @wgraham mentions in his comment above, since an `int` has no uppercase/lowercase, the `ToUpper()` call is not necessary.  However, there is no `ToString()` overload for `int` in Linq, so you have to cast it to `double` or `decimal` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6356487/3101082).

Example: `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)d.RVH_ID_).Contains(searchString)`

Comment: Ah this makes sense. I added in the ToString, but it is putting out the error    : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Perhaps you can use type casting, like so: `((string)d.RVH_ID_).ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));`

Comment: It says "cannot convert type int to string". Is it not possible to do?

Comment: Please see my edit.  It looks like you will have to use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` to be able to get a `string` out of an `int`

Comment: thank you so much! I added this code and then added using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;